# Accessing a Syncfusion Dropdown through Selenium Unit Tests

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, syncfusion

In my unit test, I'm trying to assert that a user can access and select an item from a dropdown menu. I have built every `.FindElement()` extension I can do, but when running the Unit Test it isn't finding the dropdown menu. Could anybody help me figure out how to select it? The list of dropdown items comes from a list built elsewhere in the code base.

@ Syncfusion Dropdown List Code

```
<SfDropDownList TItem="Industry" TValue="string" Placeholder="Select..." PopupHeight="20px" DataSource="@Industries" AllowFiltering="true" @bind-Value="Industry" ID="industry">
    <DropDownListEvents TItem="Industry" TValue="string" ValueChange="@(ChangeIndustry)"></DropDownListEvents>
    <DropDownListFieldSettings Text="IndustryName"></DropDownListFieldSettings>
</SfDropDownList>
```

@Test

```
var industry = driver.FindElement(By.Id("industry"));
var selectElement = new SelectElement(industry);
selectElement.SelectByText("Construction");

//Assert
Assert.Contains("Construction", industry.Text);
```

@HTML

```
<div class="mb-2 position-relative">
        <label class="label-client" for="Industry">Industry</label>
            -- <Dropdown Code Above> --
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the generated HTML from the browser for the dropdown.

Comment: Screenshots are great to see the UI but code and HTML should be in text format. It helps in readability as well as we can just copy the text and reuse it quickly for our own debugging. I left instructions on how to get the desired HTML under my answer below.

Comment: Now that you've updated the actual HTML of the dropdown... is there actually anything in that dropdown? I'm confused by the HTML you posted... it looks empty, like there are no options contained in that dropdown.

Comment: On second thought... maybe the options aren't created until the dropdown is opened for the first time? Maybe that's why the dropdown HTML you posted looks empty? Anyway... something for you to look into and update the question once you find the answer. Is there any way you can post a link to the page so we can see for ourselves?

Comment: Hi Jeff, I'm not able to post the page link anywhere as it isn't deployed to a website yet, still in development process and I can't really share much more than I already have about it. I will say this though, looking at the HTML, the Syncfusion dropdown menu sits in the `<input>` row I posted. I've repasted the HTML code to make it more clear. It grabs a List `Industry` and populates the dropdown with that List upon clicking on it, hence why I've tried to use `.FindElement(By.Id("industry"))`

Comment: From the page, are there any values in the dropdown when it's opened? It looks empty from the HTML you've posted. Perhaps the options are elsewhere in the HTML. Try the same steps as before but click the dropdown to open it, right-click on one of the options, and choose to Inspect. Do you see options there? If so, follow the same steps as before and edit them into your question.

Comment: Hi Jeff, not that I can see. I think the way the component has been built, it would be easier for me to find an item in the dropdown menu by using `.FindElement(By.Text())` or something similar. I'm just struggling to find the actual dropdown for Selenium to select to begin with.

Comment: Are you saying the dropdown has no values currently? If not, I'm not sure how you're going to do anything with it. I would ask a dev (?) to add some sample values so you can get past this portion of test writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the XPath I was using was wrong, even though I'd followed it through with the generated HTML, I installed the Selenium Edge Extension and used this to record the test I was doing. There is an option in there to change the outputs from CSS select to XPath, which gave me the correct path I was looking for.

I think it must be something to do with the way Syncfusion components generate once the browser is loaded up, but the class and IDs were completely different to the ones I had thought they were. Thanks for the help @JeffC!

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectElement` class is only for the SELECT HTML element and can't be used here. You'll have to click the element to open the dropdown and then find the desired element based on text contained using an XPath. You haven't provided the HTML generated in the browser for the dropdown so I can't provide a specific locator but this should give you the general idea.

```
var industry = driver.FindElement(By.Id("industry"));
industry.click(); // open the dropdown
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[.='Sample option']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the response. That makes a lot more sense that I was missing a step. Do you mean for me to provide a picture of the browser? As the Syncfusion Component is wrapped in a single `div`, and then the Syncfusion component is inside of that `div`.

Comment: Navigate to the page in the browser. Inspect the dropdown in question to open the dev console. Right-click on the top level element that corresponds to the dropdown and choose "Edit as HTML." Now select and copy all the contained text (you may need to simplify/shorten it if it's really long). Paste that text into some HTML beautifier online to format it up nice. Now edit your question and post the formatted text.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I've done that now. Sorry, misinterpreted what you said there.

Comment: @BenPugh No problem. It looks good now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a generic locator that you can try. Just update "Sample option" in the XPath with an actual Industry label from the dropdown and this should work. If you can find the HTML that contains the options from the Industry dropdown I can update the locator to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below code to select the value in the dropdown.

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Select item when click the list item")]
        public async Task SelectItem()
        {
            var data = GetDataItems();
            var dropdown = RenderComponent<SfDropDownList<string, Countries>>(parameters =>
                    parameters.Add(p => p.DataSource, data).AddChildContent<DropDownListFieldSettings>(field => field.Add(p => p.Text, "Name").Add(p => p.Value, "Code")));
            await dropdown.Instance.ShowPopup();
            var popupEle = dropdown.Find(".e-popup");
            var liColl = popupEle.QuerySelectorAll("li.e-list-item");
            liColl[3].Click();
            Assert.Contains("e-active", liColl[3].ClassName);
            Assert.Contains("Cameroon", dropdownlist.Instance.Text);
            var focusItem = popupEle.QuerySelector("li.e-item-focus");
            Assert.Null(focusItem);
        }
        private List<Countries> GetDataItems()
        {
            return new List<Countries>
            {
                new Countries() { Name = "Australia", Code = "AU" },
                new Countries() { Name = "Bermuda", Code = "BM" },
                new Countries() { Name = "Canada", Code = "CA" },
                new Countries() { Name = "Cameroon", Code = "CM" },
                new Countries() { Name = "Denmark", Code = "DK" },
                new Countries() { Name = "France", Code = "FR" }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).